# Summing iterations in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, iteration

I have the following code:

```
xRange=[1 length(delta1)];
yRange=[-80 0];
box11=(delta1>=xRange(1)) & (delta1 <= xRange(2)) & (Sref1 >= yRange(1)) & (Sref1 <=     yRange(2));
delta11=delta1(box11);
Sref11=Sref1(box11);
size11=sum(box11(:));
size1=numel(delta1); % or numel(y); whatever floats your boat
perc1=(size11/size1)*100;
```

and it works well but the problem is that when I put it inside a loop it will calculate perc1 for one time only, I want summation of perc1 for all loops (i.e. sum of all percentages). how can I do it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inizialize perc1=0 before the cycle and change perc1= perc1 + (size11/size1)*100 in the loop.

Comment: thanks for your response. when I apply your idea I get one percentage number. but when I calculate it manually I get other number ?!

I do this perc1= (perc1 + (size11/size1)*100)/i in order to get the average percentage of all iterations

Comment: no you cannot divide perc1 by i in the cycle for the average. you have to define another variable avg = perc1/i because perc1 is the sum of all the percentage calculated up to the ith cycle

Comment: if you want to do a continuos average of the percentage without new variables you can do

if i==1, perc1 = size11/size1*100;
else perc1 = ( perc1*(i-1) + size11/size1*100 )/i;
end,

but the introduction of an 'if' reduces the speed of the algorithm